# UITableView Scroll is not work in inside UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, uitabview

I add UITableView inside UIScrollView. It's working fine. UITableView width is 1200. I move scroll to over 320 , I can't scroll and click in UITableView. Between 0 and 320px, it's working fine. Over 320, UIScrollView is dragging the UITableview and can't scroll and can't clik ,too.

Edit:

I add

```
scrollview.contentSize = CGSizeMake(1200, 1);
```

Scrollview is not dragging now. However, can't scroll down in UITableView over 320px width.

Comment: If you are trying horizontal scroll of table view,then its possible so you might be making some small mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

Increase the scroll view content size height to the height of the table.If the height is 1 then how are u adding a table as a subview to a scroll view of height 1.

Comment: when I change to 1, UIscrollview can drag horizontal only. UITableView can scroll. Over 340px width cell, can't scroll.